# In Uno when playing a Wild Draw 4 card, can I choose a color not in my hand?

Tags: uno

If I play a Wild Draw 4 card and the only card I have left in my hand is a red one, can I change the color to green?
Or is it required to have the called color?

Comment: It is a decent strategy if you only have one card left to not call that color.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that. In [the rules](https://www.unorules.com/), there is nothing restricting the color called.

> **Wild** – This card represents all four colors, and can be placed on any
> card. The player has to state which color it will represent for the
> next player. It can be played regardless of whether another card is
> available. If turned up at the beginning of play, **the first player
> chooses what color to continue play.**
>
> **Wild Draw Four** – This acts just
> like the wild card except that the next player also has to draw four
> cards as well as forfeit his/her turn. With this card, you must have
> no other alternative cards to play that matches the color of the card
> previously played. If you play this card illegally, you may be
> challenged by the other player to show your hand to him/her. If
> guilty, you need to draw 4 cards. If not, the challenger needs to draw
> 6 cards instead. If turned up at the beginning of play, return this
> card to the Draw pile, shuffle, and turn up a new one.